# Reject incomming calls using AT-commands (uBlox LARA-R211)

Tags: at-command, modem

I am using a module by uBlox (LARA-R211 with a SIM-card) which I need to get my device online. My problem is that sometimes the module is receiving a phone call, making the module abort all other procedures, which is unwanted. 
The module is configured with AT-commands, and uBlox has released documentation regarding this.

I want to set my module in such a way, that it rejects/blocks/ignores all incomming calls.

I've searched through the documentation, and found that I might need to use the "AT+CLCK"-command, so I tried that. I immediately ran into the issue, that I need a password to use this command, which I dont have. I noticed that they (uBlox in their documentation) uses the SIMs PIN-code as password, but my SIM card has no PIN (SIM provider said that it's set to "0000" when PIN code is not required)
I tried using the "0000" code, but with no results. I've tried the following commands, but with no success:

```
AT+CLCK="AI",1,"0000"
AT+CLCK="AI",0,"0000"
AT+CLCK="AI",1,""
AT+CLCK="AI",0,""
```

I expected some sort of reaction and a "OK" statement to symbolise that the command has been implemented. Instead i get "ERROR" for each of the commands stated above

Comment: Issue AT+CMEE=1 to request more detailed error messages instead of the plain "ERROR"

Comment: Thanks, I'll update with results

Comment: ... I got "+CME ERROR: 100" where 100 stands for "unidentified", no matter which of the commands stated above I use

Comment: Does AT+CLCK=? report an error?

Comment: No, it does not. It report the list of compatible commands. When sending the command "AT+CLCK=?" I get:
"+CLCK: ("AO","OI","AI","IR","OX","AB","AG","AC","PS","PN","PU","PP","PC","SC","FD")"

Comment: Odd, the only thing that looks like it could cause a problem would be an invalid pin - but that has a specific CME error code that you would expect to see.

Comment: @AlexK. yea, that's what I thought. Any other ideas about what could be wrong is appreciated. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: No more ideas I'm afraid, the pwd is probably optional so you could try `AT+CLCK="AI",1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To whoever it might interest:

The functions mentionen above require a password, and it seems that this specific module can't handle any password-depending commands, if the PIN code on the used SIM card is deactivated. My guess, since the password is by default set to the SIMs PIN code, is that the module can't compare the password inputted in the command with the PIN code, and therefore returns "password incorrect", making all password-depending unuseable.

I've contacted the producers of the module, so hopefully they will fix this error in future products, if my assumption is correct.

Another solution I found to be working similarly, is to use the command `AT+CGCLASS='CG'`

Answer (score 1):

I've not enough reputation to add a comment to previous answer.

But if it's true that incoming calls cannot be barred if the PIN code on the used SIM card is deactivated, maybe you can:

1. Activate temporarily PIN code on the SIM card, by issuing 'AT+CLCK="SC",1,TEMP_PIN'
2. Issue the command(s) that used to raise an ERROR (for example 'AT+CLCK="AI",0,TEMP_PIN)
3. Dectivate the PIN check again by issuing 'AT+CLCK="SC",0,TEMP_PIN'

PS: don't rely too much on the verbose error enabled with +CMEE=1/2, because it is often inaccurate. "+CME ERROR: 100" sounds like typical *fallback error code*. This is true for every modem manufacturer.

Comment: Hey Cubo78. I found a workaround to achieve the functionality I need, but thanks for the answer anyway! Might be useful for future implementations. I'll give an upvote. Cheers mate